# XNAMath SIMD performance

Tags: c++, math, directx, simd, directx-11

I tested XNAMath perfomance and looks like on my pc version with SIMD intrinsics has lower perfomance than without simd.

I use function that calculates dot product.
I tested this code as without simd:

```
XMVECTOR4 Result;
Result.m128_f32[0] =
Result.m128_f32[1] =
Result.m128_f32[2] =
Result.m128_f32[3] = V1.m128_f32[0] * V2.m128_f32[0] + V1.m128_f32[1] * V2.m128_f32[1] + V1.m128_f32[2] * V2.m128_f32[2] + V1.m128_f32[3] * V2.m128_f32[3];
return Result;
```

And this with:

```
XMVECTOR4 vTemp2 = V2;
XMVECTOR4 vTemp = _mm_mul_ps(V1,vTemp2);
vTemp2 = _mm_shuffle_ps(vTemp2,vTemp,_MM_SHUFFLE(1,0,0,0)); // Copy X to the Z position and Y to the W position
vTemp2 = _mm_add_ps(vTemp2,vTemp);          // Add Z = X+Z; W = Y+W;
vTemp = _mm_shuffle_ps(vTemp,vTemp2,_MM_SHUFFLE(0,3,0,0));  // Copy W to the Z position
vTemp = _mm_add_ps(vTemp,vTemp2);           // Add Z and W together
return XM_PERMUTE_PS(vTemp,_MM_SHUFFLE(2,2,2,2));    // Splat Z and return
```

And in this loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
{
    volatile XMVECTOR4 d = MVector4Dot(v1, v2);
}
```

In release mode version without simd takes about 9ms, and with about 20.

Which reasons may affect SIMD performance?

Thanx.

**UPDATE:** I compile program with "/arch:SSE2" option

Comment: Take a look at the disassembly and make sure the code is actually doing anything. It's quite common for a compiler to optimize heavily a contrived "benchmark", in a way not representative for a real-world program.

Comment: Сompiler generates asm code inside a loop.

Comment: Also i think if compiler "cut" bechmark code i would have receive a result about 0ms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSE isn't really set up for this - you are trying to add 'horizontally' which isn't a good fit for SIMD. You might search (Google or S.O.) array-of-structures vs. structure-of-arrays, for more detailed answers. I can tell you that if your processor supports SSE3, you have:

```
/* apologies - this is 'C' ... */

v0 = _mm_mul_ps(V1, V2);
v0 = _mm_hadd_ps(v0, v0);
v0 = _mm_hadd_ps(v0, v0); /* dot product splat across all elements. */
```

Again, the 'haddps' has a very high latency - fewer instructions, but probably slower than the code without SIMD. Once you start interleaving operations, it may be possible to hide the latencies. If your processor supports SSE 4.1, you can use:

```
v0 = _mm_dp_ps(V1, V2, 0xff); /* dot product splat across all elements. */
```

If your code targets more recent processors, this *might* yield better performance.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but code in question copied from XNAMathLibrary from Windows8 SDK - it's not mine